# Can I safely change C# app settings from User scope to Application scope?

Tags: c#, .net

Our application has a number of settings that have been mistakenly defined as User scope.  I want to change them to Application scope.  However, as the app has already been distributed is this safe to do?  Specifically, will the next version of the app ignore any user specific values and just revert to using the application scope values distributed with the application?

Comment: I'd find out by creating a tiny dummy app with a User scope app setting then change it to Application scope. Shouldn't take long to put together and test. :)

Comment: Define "safe". You can easily change the scope. You may not have to make any code modifications if you treat the settings as read-only. How are you going to *migrate* existing settings though? Which of the many user settings will you keep? How are you going to *change* them in the future? By redeploying the application?

Comment: I don't want to retain any user values for these settings.  I just want to be sure .NET will correctly ignore the old user values and just use the Application level values.